# How can I find the area bounded by given curves?

Tags: calculus, integration, area, parametric

> Find the area bounded by the curve and the axes whose parametric equations are
>   $$
> x=a\cos 2\theta, \quad y=b\sin 2\theta,
> $$
>   where $0\leqslant \theta\leqslant\pi$ and $0<a<b$, from $x=0$ to $x=a$.

---

I've attempted it multiple times and I got $0.785ab$, whereas the given answer is $1.57ab$.

Comment: Could you show your procedure?

Answer (score 1):

$$A=\int_0^\pi x(\theta)y'(\theta)d\theta$$ 
$$\frac{dy}{d\theta}=2b\cos(2\theta)$$
$$a\int_0^\pi \cos(2\theta)2b\cos(2\theta)d\theta$$
$$2ab\int_0^\pi \cos^2(2\theta)d\theta$$ Use $2\theta=u$ where $2d\theta=du$
$$ab\int \cos^2(u)du$$
$$\frac{ab}{2}\int \cos(2u)+1du$$
$$\frac{ab}{2}[ \frac{\sin(2u)}{2}+u]$$
$$\frac{ab}{2}[ \frac{\sin(4\theta)}{2}+2\theta]$$ From our initial integration limits apply $\theta$ on $\pi$ and $0$
$$\frac{ab}{2}[\frac{\sin(4\pi)}{2}+2\pi-\frac{\sin(0)}{2}-0]$$
Which leads to $ab\pi$ which is congruent to any circle or ellipse described by the parametric equations. I didnt understand the question but if you were to take the positive side of x or y you would get the response you needed

Comment: Here're my steps: 
A=∫0π/4y(θ)x'(θ)d(θ)
=ab∫0π/4 -2sin^2(2θ)dθ
=π/4 ab

Comment: Let me see if I got it right $$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}y(θ)x'(θ)d(θ) =ab\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} -2sin^2(2θ)dθ =\frac \pi4 ab $$
If so why are you integrating from 0 to $\frac \pi4$

Answer (score 0):

The standard parameterisation of ellipse of form $$\dfrac {x^2}{a^2} + \dfrac {y^2}{b^2} = 1$$

is $x = a \cos t$ and $ y = b \sin t$ for $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$, the area of such a ellipse is $ab\pi$.

Let $ \theta = \dfrac{t}2$, where $ 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$ and then $x = a \cos(2 \theta)$ and $ y = b\sin (2\theta)$.

We need to find the area from $x = 0 \left(\theta = \dfrac\pi2 \right)$ to $ x = a  \left(\theta = 0 \right)$, which is a half of the ellipse. Hence the given area is $\dfrac\pi2ab$.